# How can you use variable substitution in visual basic to referance object names?

Tags: vb.net, object, visual-studio-2015

I have been writing bash scripts for the last few months but have a Visual Basic Window Forms app I need to write and hit a wall. I think bash ruined me. This is probably glaringly obvious but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a few labels and radio buttons I need to iterate through and do some checks on while I can do this for each one of course it really bloats the code i.e. 20 buttons and 20 labels is 40 extra lines for each check.
So the question is: if I have for example radiobutton1,radiobutton2,radiobutton3...or label1,label2,label3... how can I reference them using variable substitution or whats a work around? This will be useful no matter the object type because of the way VB names stuff.

```
for i = 1 to 3
t=cstr(i)
  if radiobutton# $t %t (t) {t}.Checked= true then "-EXAMPLES"
    label# $t %t (t) {t}.Text ="You Clicked Me On"
  end if
next
```

Anyway, I have been looking all morning, 4 hours now, and can't seem to find the solution. I do need to be able to use the objects' properties etc..

Comment: You put the objects in a list and then iterate over or enumerate that list. There are numerous ways you can do that, e.g. `For Each btn In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()`.

Comment: To determine which `RadioButton` is checked, e.g. `Dim selection = Me.Controls.OfType(Of RadioButton)().Single(Function(opt) opt.Checked)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i = 1 to 3
  Dim rb as Radiobutton = CType(Me.controls("RadioButton" & i.ToString), RadioButton)
  if rb.Checked = true then 
    Dim lab as Label = CType(Me.controls("Label" & i.ToString), Label)
    lab.Text ="You Clicked Me On"
  end if
next
```

...well, I hope I got your idea correctly.

Here is a way to handle radio buttons in different containers:

```
Dim RBlist as List(Of RadioButton)
RBlist.Add(Me.RadioButton1)
RBlist.Add(Me.RadioButton2)
RBlist.Add(Me.RadioButton3)

For Each rb in RBlist
    If rb.Checked = True Then
        ...
    End If
Next
```

Alternatively, if you need to expose iteration, you can write the last bit like this:

```
For ir = 0 to RBlist.Count - 1
    If RBlist(ir).Checked = True Then
        ...
    End If
Next
```

Notice, that when adding radio buttons to a list, it doesn't matter which parent container are they placed in. The best time to add the RadioButtons to the list is when you create them.

If you need different objects (such as Labels, Buttons, NumericUpDowns,...), you have to create a List(Of Object) for each of them separately. There are other possible data structures, but this one is pretty straight-forward and proven.

Comment: Oakthat is exactly what i was looking for and what I had tried a number of times but i keep getting a null exception. It turns out that since i have the radio buttons on different panels that I am not getting the proper data from the  CType(Me.Controls(key:="RadioButton17".ToString), RadioButton)

Comment: so my problem is how do it get the data for the button into a variable from the panels? Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(Me.RadioButton1) is typical

Comment: You need to get it through the parent container of the particular control. If you added it via Me.Panel1.Add(rb) then you reference it Me.Panel1.Controls(STRING_NAME), where string name is composed as per code shown in my answer. If you have different parent containers, you'll probably have to loop thrugh whole structure. Another goof way is to create a list. I'll provide you an example in my answer.